# Chamar app Gmail a partir do meu app. E enviar email a partir da minha aplicação

Tags: android

Já pesquisei sobre as duas funções, mas tudo que encontro é muito vago.

1. Preciso enviar um email a partir do meu aplicativo, diretamente para uma conta qualquer de email (que é a do meu usuário).
2. E o meu outro problema é chamar o aplicativo do Gmail a partir do meu app.

Uso intent/content provider?

Comment: Vc quer anexar algum arquivo também?

Comment: não. quero só enviar um texto, somente!

Answer (score 2):

Se quiser abrir apenas um aplicativo de e-mail com o e-mail do destinatario ja preenchido basta usar esse intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + url));
startActivity(intent);
```

Se não a pagina do android developer indica usar essa forma, mais completa

```
public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Página do Android Developer: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html?hl=pt-br#Email

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar um ShareCompat.IntentBuilder se estiver utilizando biblioteca de compatibilidade.

```
final Intent intent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(getActivity())
                      .setType("message/rfc822")
                      .setSubject("Seu assunto")
                      .setText("corpo do email")
                      .setChooserTitle("Titulo da tela de seleção")
                      .createChooserIntent();

startActivity(intent);
```

Com esse código o usuário pode selecionar qualquer aplicativo no celular que pode enviar uma mensagem, entre eles o GMAIL.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Tens algum feedback dessa resposta?